# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo (PhoneGap)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am fixing a phonegap app at work but got this issue and have no idea how to fix it since im new with it all of this.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{za.gov.app_v2/za.gov.app_v2}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "za.gov.app_v2" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/za.gov.app_v2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/za.gov.app_v2-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "za.gov.app_v2" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/za.gov.app_v2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/za.gov.app_v2-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2183)
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10001" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="za.gov.app_v2" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you installed plugins ?

Comment: Im not sure what the former developer installed. Is there a way that i can see what they installed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue.

Open `config.xml` in your application root.

Look for lines that are as the one below:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
```

Each line that starts with `<gap:plugin` will be a plugin.

You can then search the plugin at [plugins.cordova.io](http://plugins.cordova.io/) by name (written in the `name` attribute) and install it with your CMD.